# To add background-image with vuejs and looks good

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am  working with Vue.js, In a  component  which I am working  should to set background-image and wrap all content into it. I have done until now as below:

```js
<script>
export default {
    name: "AppHero",
    data(){
     return{
      image: { backgroundImage: "url(https://i.postimg.cc/0NbqSxfQ/banner-image.png)" }      
        };
    },
    props: {
    titlehero: String,
    subtitle: String,

  }
}

</script>
```

```css
.home-hero{
    // background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/0NbqSxfQ/banner-image.png");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div :style="image" class="home-hero">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h3 class="fw-bold" >{{titlehero }}</h3>     
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Also I am sharing my link in the codepene:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/vena/pen/ZEjJmme)

My background-image looks like screenshot below:
but right results should to be such as  design on Figma:
Any idea to fixed this.?
Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try background-size: contain. You should also set the width of the element to `100vw` instead of `100%`. That way the div will be the width of the screen.

So your code should look like this:

```
.home-hero {
    background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/0NbqSxfQ/banner-image.png");
    background-size: contain; /* This changed */
    width: 100vw; /* This changed */
    height: 100vh;
}
```